# Homeomorphism $h:SU(1,1)/U(1)\longrightarrow \mathbb{H}^2$

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, homogeneous-spaces

I need find a homeomorphism $h:SU(1,1)/U(1)\longrightarrow \mathbb{H}^2$ equivariant with the action of $SU(1,1)$ onto the disk unitary $\mathbb{D}$ where

$\mathbb{H}^2={\{(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in\mathbb{R}^3: x_1^2-x_2^2-x_3^2=1, x_1 \geq1}\}$

Idea: Remember that:

$SU(1,1)={\{\left( \begin{array}{cc}
 \alpha & \beta \\
 \bar{\beta} & \bar{\alpha}
\end{array} \right)\in\mathcal{M}_{2\times2}(\mathbb{C}):(\alpha,\beta)\in\mathbb{C}^{2},\ \alpha\bar{\alpha}-\beta\bar{\beta}=1}\}
={\{\left( \begin{array}{cc}
 e^{i\theta} & 0\\
 0 & e^{-i\theta}
\end{array} \right)\left( \begin{array}{cc}
 cosh(t) & sinh(t)\\
 sinh(t) & cosh(t)
\end{array} \right)\left( \begin{array}{cc}
 e^{i\phi} & 0\\
 0 & e^{-i\phi}
\end{array} \right):\phi,\theta,t\in\mathbb{R}}\}$

Then all element of $SU(1,1)/U(1)$  we can write them the way:

$\left[\left(\begin{array}{cc}
 e^{i\theta}cosh(t) & e^{i\theta}sinh(t) \\
 e^{-i\theta}sinh(t) & e^{-i\theta}cosh(t) \end{array}\right)\right]$ where

$\left[\left(\begin{array}{cc}
 e^{i\theta}cosh(t) & e^{i\theta}sinh(t) \\
 e^{-i\theta}sinh(t) & e^{-i\theta}cosh(t) \end{array}\right)\right]=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
 e^{i\theta}cosh(t) & e^{i\theta}sinh(t) \\
 e^{-i\theta}sinh(t) & e^{-i\theta}cosh(t) \end{array}\right)U(1)$

Then maybe a map homeomorphism is
$h:SU(1,1)/U(1)\longrightarrow \mathbb{H}^2$ defined by $h(\left[\left(\begin{array}{cc}
 e^{i\theta}cosh(t) & e^{i\theta}sinh(t) \\
 e^{-i\theta}sinh(t) & e^{-i\theta}cosh(t) \end{array}\right)\right])=(cosh(t),cos(\theta)sinh(t),sinh(t)sin(\theta))$

But I have not been able to prove that $h$ is a homeomorphism. Is $h$ a homeomorphism?

Thanks.

Comment: You wrote $senh(t)$ in a few places. Is that a typo and should read $sinh(t)$?

Comment: @quarague Thanks

Comment: Alternatively, you know that projecting a point onto the plane $x_1 = 0$ along the line connecting the point with $(-1, 0, 0)$ defines a homeomorphism $h : \Bbb H^2 \to \Bbb D$, and the $SU(1, 1)$-action $\cdot$ on $\Bbb D$ conjugates to one on $\Bbb H^2$, namely, $g \bullet {\bf x} = h^{-1} (g \cdot h({\bf x}))$. Since the original action is transitive, so is the action on $\Bbb H^2$, and we can identify $\Bbb H^2 \cong SU(1, 1) / K$, where $K$ is the stabilizer of an elected point.

Comment: @Travis Hi, thanks to your suggestion I have calculated homeomorphism $h:\mathbb{H}^2\to\mathbb{D}$, $h(x_1,x_2, x_3)=\frac{x_2+ix_3}{1+x_1}$ and hence $h^{-1}:\mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{H}^2$, $h^{-1}(z)=(\frac{1+|z|^2}{1-|z|^2},\frac{z+\bar z}{1-|z|^2},\frac{z-\bar z}{i(1-|z|^2)})$  But how do I prove that $g \bullet {\bf x} = h^{-1} (g \cdot h({\bf x}))$ defines an action of $SU (1,1)$ in $\mathbb{H}^2$ ?

Comment: Oh, if $g=\left( \begin{array}{cc}
 \alpha & \beta \\
 \bar{\beta} & \bar{\alpha}
\end{array} \right)$ then $g\cdot h(\bf{x})=\frac{\alpha h(\bf{x})+ \beta}{ \bar{\beta} h(\bf{x})+ \bar{\alpha} }$?

Comment: Yes, that's the right formula, but you don't even need an explicit formula to show that $\bullet$ defines a group action. For any group action $\cdot\,:G \times B \to B$, a bijection $\phi: A \to B$ determines an action on $A$ w.r.t. which $\phi$ is equivariant by $$g \bullet a := \phi^{-1}(g \cdot \phi(a)) .$$ For example, we can verify
$$g \bullet (h \bullet a) = \phi^{-1}(g \cdot \phi(\phi^{-1}(h \cdot \phi(a)))) = \phi^{-1}(g \cdot (h \cdot \phi(a))) = \phi^{-1}((gh) \cdot \phi(a)) = (gh) \bullet a .$$

Comment: @Travis Thank you very much friend. Just out of curiosity, the mapping I proposed in question $(h:SU(1,1)/U(1)\to \mathbb{H}^2 )$ is it a homeomorphism?

Comment: It's a bit difficult to tell at a glance---from the way it was constructed it's not immediately obvious that it's well defined. I suggest trying to write $h$ in terms of the arguments of the matrix themselves, rather than parameters on which they depend.